# Laravel return value from within transactions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, transactions

I'm working with transactions in **laravel 5**, so far I have been getting the results of any method outside of the statement with a reference param `&$`, but I red this is a bad practice because the operator `&` is obsolete. Is there any other way to get the value of a `var` outside transaction scope?

this is a code example:

```
public function post(Request $request, Persona $persona)
{
    try {
        DB::transaction(function () use ($request, &$result) {          
            $result = Persona::create($request->all());
            // ... Moooore code omitted 
        });

        // Do more thing with $result 
        $result;
    } // ...
}}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `DB::beginTransaction()` and `DB::commit()` instead:

```
DB::beginTransaction();
try {
    $result = Persona::create($request->all());
    DB::commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    DB::rollBack();
}
```

[Laravel 5.5: Database Transactions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#database-transactions)

Comment: This answer should not selected as answer.
you can return the required value directly from within the closure.
please refer to
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php#L561

as recommended by 
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/how-do-i-return-a-value-from-a-call-to-dbtransactionfunction-use?page=1#reply=304366

Answer (score 2):

It's not that complicated, just return the result inside your transaction ;)

```
public function post(Request $request, Persona $persona)
{
    try {
        $result = DB::transaction(function () use ($request) {          
            $result = Persona::create($request->all());
            // ... Moooore code omitted 
            return $result;
        });

        // Do more thing with $result 
        $result;
    } // ...
}}
```

Comment: No, return inside transactions is not working for me!!

Comment: You can't return from the closure. You'd have to pass in (by reference) a variable to modify.

Comment: This perfectly work and should be selected as the correct answer.

you can return the required value directly from within the closure.
please refer to
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php#L561

as recommended by 
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/how-do-i-return-a-value-from-a-call-to-dbtransactionfunction-use?page=1#reply=304366

Answer (score 0):

```
$someVal = DB::transaction(function () {
    return $something;
});

print($someVal);
```

`DB::transaction` returns what you returns inside `closure`.